# Solve $\lambda x^2 e^x = x$ for $x$

Tags: calculus

I have a very elementary question.

Let $\lambda<0$. I want to find the values of $x$ for which $\lambda x^2 e^x = x$.

$$\lambda x^2 e^x = x \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
\lambda x e^x = 1\\
x = 0
\end{cases}$$

However, I don't know how to find the values of $x$ for which $\lambda x e^x = 1$

Comment: Have a look at Lambert $W$ function on Wikipedia.

Comment: $x=0$ is an obvious solution. But outside of that, you can divide by $\lambda x$ to get
$$
xe^x = \frac{1}{\lambda}
$$
which is a task for the Lambert W function. And that's all you can do, really ...

Answer (score 2):

Analyzing the function $xe^x$ with a graphing calculator:

[image]

We can see that the minimum value of the function is $\approx -0.37$. Any value of $\frac 1\lambda$ below this would not give us real roots. To summarize, you can get the number of roots this function has based on this approximation.

To find the exact value of the roots, you can use the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function. Given
$$xe^x = \frac 1 \lambda$$

Taking the lambert W of both sides, we get 
$$x = W\left(\frac 1 \lambda\right)$$

Which is the required solution. Note that $W$ will give you complex solutions once your value of $\frac 1 \lambda$ is less than the minimum mentioned above.

Comment: This answer should be flushed out a bit. For certain $\lambda < 0$ there are two solutions $x$, for others none at all.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt the question clearly states $\lambda < 0$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. My bad :P